# Why are my child nodes not detected without the parent node being selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, treeview, treenode

I have a treelist in my form with checkboxes enabled. I need to add anything checked to a list so I can write that list out. If I check any parent nodes (or highest level nodes) it includes them. If I select any parent nodes it also selects its children nodes (this is intentional), and displays those. But If I check any child nodes only, it won't add them to my list.

```
//check to see if there are any nodes checked
            bool nodeHasCheck = false;
            foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
            {
                if (n.Checked)
                {
                    nodeHasCheck = true;
                    break;
                }

                GetExtendedFeatures(n.Nodes);
            }

            //only return stuff if something's checked
            if (nodeHasCheck == true)
            {

                foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
                {
                    if (n.Checked)
                    {
                        //n.BackColor = Color.Black;
                        nodeList.Add(n.Text);
                    }

                    GetExtendedFeatures(n.Nodes);
                }
```

It also appears that if I select 2 parent nodes, the recursion that occurs (Think that's the right term) is causing it to find the first checked node, then starts over, and adds that same checked node a second time before it hits the second set of nodes.

I provided my node test, hopefully it's enough to identify why it's not detecting child nodes selected without the parent node selected.

UPDATED - 3/18/13 
My button click code:

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScanNodes(treeView1.Nodes[0]);                
        }
private void ScanNodes(TreeNode parent)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in parent.Nodes)
            {
                if (node.Checked)
                {
                    nodeList.Add(node.Text.ToString());
                }
                if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    ScanNodes(node);
                }
            }


                var message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, nodeList);
                message = message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ", ");



                MessageBox.Show(message);
                nodeList.Clear();

        }
```

Comment: I dont see the recursion here, unless GetExtendedFeatures is actually the method code you are showing. For your current code it only loops through child nodes of checked parents. ayou have to loop across all nodes and see if they are selected or not, then adding to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a List of all the selected nodes in a TreeView you can use the following:

Supose the list is named `nodeList`:

```
    //We First declare a recursive method to loop through all nodes, 
//we need to pass a root node to start 
    private void ScanNodes(TreeNode parent)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in parent.Nodes)
                {
                    if (node.Checked)
                    {
                        nodeList.Add(node.Text);
                    }
                    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ScanNodes(node);
                    }
                }
            }
```

With that set up You just need to call the ScanNodes method and pass the root node of your TreeView:

```
ScanNodes(treeView1.Nodes[0]);
```

Regards,

Comment: I added your method, then added that call to the ScanNodes method to my run button, then added a messagebox to show the nodes that were selected but it remains empty. None of my checked nodes are triggering your check and unfortunately I don't understand why.

Comment: The code of ScanNodes does not return a value just saves the text property of checked nodes to a list, can you post your button_click code?

Comment: Ok I see, just take the code block you added to the ScanNodes method and put it inside your btnGenerate_Click, just after calling ScanNodes(treeView1.Nodes[0]);

Comment: It wasn't working due to the clearing of contents of your nodeList after each execution of ScanNodes. Remember ScanNodes is recursive and will call itself when needed.

Comment: Moved that call out of the method and added it to the end of the button click event and sure enough it is working correctly. Thanks so much echavez, enjoy the best answer vote :)